# Access 97 hide or show an Image by checkin a value of the query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working with an old access 97 project, i can't update it. I have a continuos form that give me some results.Each row contain many values and i have one image to the right that must be hide/show by checking on of the other value returned by the query. The value that must be checked each row is named "Status" and the image that must hide/show is named Img1, so i have tried something like this:

```
Private_Sub Status_Enter()
  Valore=Status.Text
  if Valore = "O" Then
   Img1.Visible=true
  else
   Img2.Visible=false
  end if
end Sub
```

I have used Enter event cause i can't find an event that is called each time the status is created (but maybe i'm thinking too much as a php developer...), anyway this method isn't called. How i can do to achive this result: An image that hide/show each row by check the value of "each row Status".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `Current` event of the form.

However, setting the `Visible` property of `Img1` control in the `Current` event is not going to help you as it will show/hide the control for all the records.

From `Access 2000`and onward you would be able to use conditional formatting to enable/disable the image, but not to show/hide it. Anyway, in `Access 97` this feature is not available.

Answer (score -1):

You may need something like this:

```
Private_Sub Status_Enter()
  Dim Valore As Boolean
  Valore = (Me!Status.Value = "0")
  Me!Img1.Visible = Valore
  Me!Img2.Visible = Not Valore
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but in this way all the Img1 of all rows are hiding at the same time... I need to set the visibility of Img1 of a specified row. Do you know how i can achive it? Maybe Status_Enter () is not the correct event, but i can't find a place where i can write this code to loop in throught the row creation...

Comment: That you cannot do. The status and properties for an unbound control (of any kind) will be the same for all records on a continous form.